# How to control the loading of my css

Tags: html, css, web, sprite-sheet

I'm just making my first website with Ember and Node.js. My application loads many images and to speed it up I've made a number of css spritesheets for each page so that it can load what the user sees first and then download content down the page when it's finished doing that.

My problem is that the css seems to load in parallel so all my spritesheets for that page get loaded at the same time anyway.

How can I load my css in series?

Comment: You can add style-sheets dynamically with JavaScript. Browsers don't download images from CSS until they are used in the DOM though so I'm not sure if I understand your problem.

Comment: You mean at the same time? You can put all your CSS in one file or you have to use different (sub)domains. Most browsers only allow a few request at the same time.

Comment: How does the javascript know what page I'm on and what file needs to be loaded? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You put all of your CSS in the same stylesheet. Load it once.